# fetch(url) modifies the url before sending it

Tags: javascript, html

in my front end I am using the following code to fetch an url from a local node.js server:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3000/search/house')
.then(....
```

When I check what it sends to the server (in the network tab in developer tools of the Firefox browser) I see

```html
GET http://localhost:3000/?input=house
```

Does someone have an idea why the url is modified? (Sorry, I am a beginner!)

Thank you very much!
Joe F.

EDIT: Here is a minimal example. First the front end:

```js
function search() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/search/house')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log('data: ' + data);
    });
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {font-size: 35px;}
h2 {font-size: 24px; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline;}

/* Loginseite betreffend */
.login-form {
    width: 300px;
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.login-form h1 {
    color: #4d4d4d;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
.login-form input[type="password"],
.login-form input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #dddddd;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.login-form input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #535b63;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* Topnav (Menü) betreffend */
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(35, 135, 212);
}
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 18px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    min-width: 80px;
}
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
.topnav a.logout {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
}

/* Home Seite betreffend */
.content {
    width: 1000px;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.grid-area {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    background-color: rgb(35, 135, 212);
    border: black, 20px;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "l1 ro"
        "l2 ro"
        "l3 ro"
        "l4 ru"
}
#boxHomeButton {grid-area: l1;}
#boxInputButton {grid-area: l2;}
#boxStatisticButton {grid-area: l3;}
#boxSettingsButton {grid-area: l4;}
#boxQuerySelection {
    grid-area: ro;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 320px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    /* border: black 1px solid; */
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#boxQueryButton {grid-area: ru;}

.grid-areaSearch {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    background-color: rgb(35, 135, 212);
    border: black, 20px;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "row1"
        "row2"
}
#inputText {
    grid-area: row1;
}
#searchResultTable {
    grid-area: row2;
}
.button {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
    border: black 3px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.textInput {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
    border: black 3px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.checkbox {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.checkbox_left {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 50px;
}
.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1099px) {
    .grid-area {
        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
        grid-template-rows: 16.7% 16.7% 49,9% 16.7%;
        grid-template-areas: 
        "l1 r1"
        "l2 r2"
        "m1 m1"
        "m2 m2"
    }
    #boxHomeButton {grid-area: l1;}
    #boxInputButton {grid-area: r1;}
    #boxStatisticButton {grid-area: l2;}
    #boxSettingsButton {grid-area: r2;}
    #boxQuerySelection {grid-area: m1;}
    #boxQueryButton {grid-area: m2;}
    .button {
        margin: 10px auto;
        border-radius: 7px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vokabeltrainer</title>
        <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
        <script src="vTrainer_.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1 id="elementSearch(0)">Loading...</h1>
        <div class="content" id="divSearchContent">

            <section class="grid-areaSearch">
                <div class="box" id="boxSearchText">
                    <form>
                        <label for="textInput">Enter a word and click enter:</label>
                        <input type="input" class="textInput" name="input" id="textInput" onclick="search()">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="box" id="searchResultTable"></div>
            </section>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the backend (which you won't need I guess):

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const util = require('util');
const session = require('express-session');
const path = require('path');

// parse HTTP POST Data 
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json()) // To parse the incoming requests with JSON payloads

// put client-side code (html/css/js) in the frontend folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../frontend/'));

connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'joe',
    password : 'xxx',
    database : 'vocabulary_trainer'
});

connection.connect((err) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log('Error connecting to DB: change connection settings!');
    } else {
        console.log('Connection established!');
    }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

const dbQuery = util.promisify(connection.query).bind(connection); // gehört zum Modul util

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    console.log("got a request")
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../frontend/vTrainer_.html'));
});

app.get("/search/:keyWord", async function(request, response) { // Suchergebnisse aus Datenbank holen

    if (request.session.loggedin) { 
        let searchResult = await dbQuery("SELECT * FROM words where proposedWord = ? or associatedWord1 = ? or associatedWord2 = ?;", [request.params.keyWord, request.params.keyWord, request.params.keyWord]);
        response.json(searchResult);
    } else {
        response.json({success: 'No.'});
    }
    
});
```

Comment: `fetch()` is unable to "modify the url" in the way you've suggested. Please provide a [example] that demonstrates the behavior you see. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the fetch code.
The issue is the search function, never called. Pressing Enter will trigger the form submission. You need to add an event listener on `keydown` and call `event.preventDefault()`, this way the form should not be submitted.

```js
function search(event) {
  if (event.keyCode !== 13) return; //not enter pressed
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/search/house')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log('data: ' + data);
    });
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {font-size: 35px;}
h2 {font-size: 24px; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline;}

/* Loginseite betreffend */
.login-form {
    width: 300px;
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.login-form h1 {
    color: #4d4d4d;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
.login-form input[type="password"],
.login-form input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #dddddd;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.login-form input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #535b63;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* Topnav (Menü) betreffend */
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(35, 135, 212);
}
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 18px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    min-width: 80px;
}
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
.topnav a.logout {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
}

/* Home Seite betreffend */
.content {
    width: 1000px;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.grid-area {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    background-color: rgb(35, 135, 212);
    border: black, 20px;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "l1 ro"
        "l2 ro"
        "l3 ro"
        "l4 ru"
}
#boxHomeButton {grid-area: l1;}
#boxInputButton {grid-area: l2;}
#boxStatisticButton {grid-area: l3;}
#boxSettingsButton {grid-area: l4;}
#boxQuerySelection {
    grid-area: ro;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 320px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    /* border: black 1px solid; */
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#boxQueryButton {grid-area: ru;}

.grid-areaSearch {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    background-color: rgb(35, 135, 212);
    border: black, 20px;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "row1"
        "row2"
}
#inputText {
    grid-area: row1;
}
#searchResultTable {
    grid-area: row2;
}
.button {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
    border: black 3px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.textInput {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
    border: black 3px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.checkbox {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.checkbox_left {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 50px;
}
.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1099px) {
    .grid-area {
        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
        grid-template-rows: 16.7% 16.7% 49,9% 16.7%;
        grid-template-areas: 
        "l1 r1"
        "l2 r2"
        "m1 m1"
        "m2 m2"
    }
    #boxHomeButton {grid-area: l1;}
    #boxInputButton {grid-area: r1;}
    #boxStatisticButton {grid-area: l2;}
    #boxSettingsButton {grid-area: r2;}
    #boxQuerySelection {grid-area: m1;}
    #boxQueryButton {grid-area: m2;}
    .button {
        margin: 10px auto;
        border-radius: 7px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vokabeltrainer</title>
        <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
        <script src="vTrainer_.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1 id="elementSearch(0)">Loading...</h1>
        <div class="content" id="divSearchContent">

            <section class="grid-areaSearch">
                <div class="box" id="boxSearchText">
                    <form>
                        <label for="textInput">Enter a word and click enter:</label>
                        <input type="input" class="textInput" name="input" id="textInput" onkeydown="search(event)">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="box" id="searchResultTable"></div>
            </section>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the good expanation. It helped a lot and now it works!

Comment: if it worked then accept the answer